# menu button styling

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to make a menu button that should look like this when it is hovered:

[image]

But I made some thing that looks like this

[image]

You may notice the black border is not square as first image.

Here is my code (CSS):

```
#menu a:hover{
    border-top: 5px solid #333333;
    border-left: 5px solid #666666;
    border-right: 5px solid #666666;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666666;
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: What if you only specify the top border?

Comment: I did. But still there is a spike. I mean it is not square.

Answer (score 0):

It might look a bit goofy without any padding.. so this is what I'd recommend.  Stack overflow's pound symbol got cut out from the CSS signature

```
#menu a {
    border-top: 5px solid #333333;
    border-left: 5px solid #666666;
    border-right: 5px solid #666666;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666666;
    background-color: #666666;
    padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px; /*<====================== added this*/
    color: #FFF;
}

#menu a:hover {
    border-top: 5px solid #333333;
    border-left: 0px solid #666666; /*<========== changed this for hover effect*/
    border-right: 5px solid #666666;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666666;
    background-color: #666666;
    padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px; /*<========================== added this*/
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will work.

```
#menu a:hover{
    border-top: 5px solid #333333;   
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFF;
}
#menu a{
    border-top: 5px solid #333333;    
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in FF5 and IE8. Looks ok. The buttons are hyperlinks in white space.
But changes style on hover as you want.

```
#menu a:hover{
    border-top: 5px solid #333;   
    background-color: #666;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```